# Class not found exception for SpotifyWebApi

Tags: exception, classpath, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception

I am creating a data plugin that uses the spotify web API. I am trying to get the artist from building a spotifyApi:
package src.main.java.edu.cmu;

```
import se.michaelthelin.spotify.SpotifyApi; import se.michaelthelin.spotify.exceptions.SpotifyWebApiException; import se.michaelthelin.spotify.model_objects.specification.Artist; import se.michaelthelin.spotify.requests.data.artists.GetArtistRequest; import org.apache.hc.core5.http.ParseException; import com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException;
    
import java.io.IOException; import java.util.concurrent.CancellationException; import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture; import java.util.concurrent.CompletionException; import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class plugin { // For all requests an access token is needed private static final SpotifyApi spotifyApi = new SpotifyApi.Builder() .setAccessToken("xxx") .build();

private static final GetArtistRequest getArtistRequest = spotifyApi.getArtist("qKRpDADUKrFeKhFHDMdfcu")
    .build();

public static void getArtist_Sync() {
try {
    // Execute the request synchronous
    final Artist artist = getArtistRequest.execute();

    // Print something's name
    System.out.println("Name: " + artist.getName());
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Something went wrong!\n" + e.getMessage());
}
}

public static void getArtist_Async() {
    try {
    // Execute the request asynchronous
    final Future<Artist> somethingFuture = getArtistRequest.executeAsync();

    // Do other things...

    // Wait for the request to complete
    final Artist something = somethingFuture.get();

    // Print something's name
    System.out.println("Name: " + something.getName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Something went wrong!\n" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    getArtist_Sync();
    getArtist_Async();
}
```

}

However, when I run my code, I get this error:

I'm not sure why it says noclassdeffound and then classnotfound... I have the jar files in my referenced libraries in java project on vscode.

```
        at se.michaelthelin.spotify.SpotifyHttpManager.<init>(SpotifyHttpManager.java:60)
        at se.michaelthelin.spotify.SpotifyHttpManager$Builder.build(SpotifyHttpManager.java:392)
        at se.michaelthelin.spotify.SpotifyApi.<clinit>(SpotifyApi.java:77)
        at se.michaelthelin.spotify.SpotifyApi$Builder.<init>(SpotifyApi.java:1807)
        at src.main.java.edu.cmu.plugin.<clinit>(plugin.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.cache.CacheConfig
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        ... 5 more
```

Here is my pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>edu.cmu.cs214</groupId>
  <artifactId>backend</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>backend</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.13.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.12.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.neovisionaries</groupId>
      <artifactId>nv-i18n</artifactId>
      <version>1.29</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient5-cache</artifactId>
      <version>5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
      <version>1.10.19</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.25</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>se.michaelthelin.spotify</groupId>
      <artifactId>spotify-web-api-java</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient5-cache</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.8</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>


  <dependencyManagement>
  

    <dependencies>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.36</version>
      </dependency>

    

      

    </dependencies>

  </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. It appears that the error stacktrace you included is incomplete and does not mention "noclassdeffound" anywhere. I also recommend fixing the formatting on your code example as there seems to be a misplaced `}`

Comment: check this out - http://javareferencegv.blogspot.com/2013/10/debugging-javalangnoclassdeffounderror.html